# Does using T-SQL OPENJSON perform faster than returning raw nvarchar value when querying large JSON Arrays?

Tags: sql, performance, t-sql, azure-sql-database, azure-sql-server

I have a table in which one of the columns is used to persist a large JSON array.

Querying the raw value appears to be *much* slower than processing the column value with OPENJSON prior to returning.

#### Question:

Is OPENJSON **actually** more performant than returning a large nvarchar value?

*Why* is it faster in this instance?

---

#### Example Schema:

```
CREATE TABLE [ExampleTable] (
    [Id]                [UNIQUEIDENTIFIER]  NOT NULL,
    [Timestamp]         [DATETIME2](7)      NOT NULL,
    [PreviousObjects]   [NVARCHAR](MAX)     NOT NULL
)
```

Each row's `PreviousObjects` value is a JSON Array, typically containing around 10,000 elements.

`Id` is the Primary Key of the Table

`Id` has a unique, clustered index

`Timestamp` has a non-unique, non-clustered index

---

#### Example Query 1:

```
SELECT TOP 1 [PreviousObjects]
FROM [ExampleTable]
ORDER BY [Timestamp] DESC
```

The above query, as you might expect, was my first attempt at getting the JSON to my application.

For a JSON Array containing 10k elements, in my Azure SQL environment, the response time tended to be 10-15 seconds.

In a local environment, using a docker-hosted instance of `mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2017-latest`, this query could take as long as 50 seconds.

IO Profile:

```
Table 'ExampleTable'. Scan count 1, logical reads 4, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 6972, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 10908.
```

Statistics Profile:

```
Rows,Executes,StmtText,StmtId,NodeId,Parent,PhysicalOp,LogicalOp,Argument,DefinedValues,EstimateRows,EstimateIO,EstimateCPU,AvgRowSize,TotalSubtreeCost,OutputList,Warnings,Type,Parallel,EstimateExecutions
1,1,"SELECT TOP 1 [PreviousObjects]
FROM [ExampleTable]
ORDER BY [Timestamp] DESC",1,1,0,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,1,NULL,NULL,NULL,0.00671277,NULL,NULL,SELECT,0,NULL
1,1,"  |--Top(TOP EXPRESSION:((1)))",1,2,1,Top,Top,TOP EXPRESSION:((1)),NULL,1,0,1E-07,4035,0.00671277,[LocalDatabase].[dbo].[ExampleTable].[PreviousObjects],NULL,ExampleTable_ROW,0,1
1,1,"       |--Nested Loops(Inner Join, OUTER REFERENCES:([LocalDatabase].[dbo].[ExampleTable].[Id]))",1,3,2,Nested Loops,Inner Join,OUTER REFERENCES:([LocalDatabase].[dbo].[ExampleTable].[Id]),NULL,1,0,4.18E-05,4043,0.00671267,"[LocalDatabase].[dbo].[ExampleTable].[Timestamp], [LocalDatabase].[dbo].[ExampleTable].[PreviousObjects]",NULL,ExampleTable_ROW,0,1
1,1,"            |--Index Scan(OBJECT:([LocalDatabase].[dbo].[ExampleTable].[IX_ExampleTable_Timestamp]), ORDERED BACKWARD)",1,4,3,Index Scan,Index Scan,"OBJECT:([LocalDatabase].[dbo].[ExampleTable].[IX_ExampleTable_Timestamp]), ORDERED BACKWARD","[LocalDatabase].[dbo].[ExampleTable].[Id], [LocalDatabase].[dbo].[ExampleTable].[Timestamp]",1,0.003125,0.000168,31,0.0032831,"[LocalDatabase].[dbo].[ExampleTable].[Id], [LocalDatabase].[dbo].[ExampleTable].[Timestamp]",NULL,ExampleTable_ROW,0,1
1,1,"            |--Clustered Index Seek(OBJECT:([LocalDatabase].[dbo].[ExampleTable].[PK_ExampleTable]), SEEK:([LocalDatabase].[dbo].[ExampleTable].[Id]=[LocalDatabase].[dbo].[ExampleTable].[Id]) LOOKUP ORDERED FORWARD)",1,6,3,Clustered Index Seek,Clustered Index Seek,"OBJECT:([LocalDatabase].[dbo].[ExampleTable].[PK_ExampleTable]), SEEK:([LocalDatabase].[dbo].[ExampleTable].[Id]=[LocalDatabase].[dbo].[ExampleTable].[Id]) LOOKUP ORDERED FORWARD",[LocalDatabase].[dbo].[ExampleTable].[PreviousObjects],1,0.003125,0.0001581,4035,0.0034412,[LocalDatabase].[dbo].[ExampleTable].[PreviousObjects],NULL,ExampleTable_ROW,0,2
```

---

#### Example Query 2:

```
DECLARE @json NVARCHAR(MAX) = (
    SELECT TOP 1 [PreviousObjects]
    FROM [ExampleTable]
    ORDER BY [Timestamp] DESC
)


SELECT *
FROM OPENJSON(@json) 
WITH ( 
    [Id] NVARCHAR(100),
    [ElementTimestamp] DATETIME2,
    [Hash] NVARCHAR(500)
)
```

This was the second query I tried, and counter-intuitively, I found this returns significantly faster than Example Query 1.

For the same dataset, in my Azure SQL environment, the response time tended to be 1-4 seconds.

In a local environment, using a docker-hosted instance of `mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2017-latest`, this query tended to consistantly return in less than 2 seconds.

Both of the results for Example Query 2 were shockingly more performant, despite containing the very same query, albiet in memory.

IO Profile:

```
Table 'ExampleTable'. Scan count 1, logical reads 4, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
```

Statistics Profile:

```
Rows,Executes,StmtText,StmtId,NodeId,Parent,PhysicalOp,LogicalOp,Argument,DefinedValues,EstimateRows,EstimateIO,EstimateCPU,AvgRowSize,TotalSubtreeCost,OutputList,Warnings,Type,Parallel,EstimateExecutions
1,1,"DECLARE @json NVARCHAR(MAX) = (
    SELECT TOP 1 [PreviousObjects]
    FROM [ExampleTable]
    ORDER BY [Timestamp] DESC
)",1,1,0,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,1,NULL,NULL,NULL,0.006718207,NULL,NULL,SELECT,0,NULL
0,0,"  |--Compute Scalar(DEFINE:([Expr1003]=[LocalDatabase].[dbo].[ExampleTable].[PreviousObjects]))",1,2,1,Compute Scalar,Compute Scalar,DEFINE:([Expr1003]=[LocalDatabase].[dbo].[ExampleTable].[PreviousObjects]),[Expr1003]=[LocalDatabase].[dbo].[ExampleTable].[PreviousObjects],1,0,1E-07,4035,0.006718207,[Expr1003],NULL,ExampleTable_ROW,0,1
1,1,"       |--Nested Loops(Left Outer Join)",1,3,2,Nested Loops,Left Outer Join,NULL,NULL,1,0,4.18E-06,4035,0.006718107,[LocalDatabase].[dbo].[ExampleTable].[PreviousObjects],NULL,ExampleTable_ROW,0,1
1,1,"            |--Constant Scan",1,4,3,Constant Scan,Constant Scan,NULL,NULL,1,0,1.157E-06,9,1.157E-06,NULL,NULL,ExampleTable_ROW,0,1
1,1,"            |--Top(TOP EXPRESSION:((1)))",1,5,3,Top,Top,TOP EXPRESSION:((1)),NULL,1,0,1E-07,4035,0.00671277,[LocalDatabase].[dbo].[ExampleTable].[PreviousObjects],NULL,ExampleTable_ROW,0,1
1,1,"                 |--Nested Loops(Inner Join, OUTER REFERENCES:([LocalDatabase].[dbo].[ExampleTable].[Id]))",1,6,5,Nested Loops,Inner Join,OUTER REFERENCES:([LocalDatabase].[dbo].[ExampleTable].[Id]),NULL,1,0,4.18E-05,4043,0.00671267,"[LocalDatabase].[dbo].[ExampleTable].[Timestamp], [LocalDatabase].[dbo].[ExampleTable].[PreviousObjects]",NULL,ExampleTable_ROW,0,1
1,1,"                      |--Index Scan(OBJECT:([LocalDatabase].[dbo].[ExampleTable].[IX_ExampleTable_Timestamp]), ORDERED BACKWARD)",1,7,6,Index Scan,Index Scan,"OBJECT:([LocalDatabase].[dbo].[ExampleTable].[IX_ExampleTable_Timestamp]), ORDERED BACKWARD","[LocalDatabase].[dbo].[ExampleTable].[Id], [LocalDatabase].[dbo].[ExampleTable].[Timestamp]",1,0.003125,0.000168,31,0.0032831,"[LocalDatabase].[dbo].[ExampleTable].[Id], [LocalDatabase].[dbo].[ExampleTable].[Timestamp]",NULL,ExampleTable_ROW,0,1
1,1,"                      |--Clustered Index Seek(OBJECT:([LocalDatabase].[dbo].[ExampleTable].[PK_ExampleTable]), SEEK:([LocalDatabase].[dbo].[ExampleTable].[Id]=[LocalDatabase].[dbo].[ExampleTable].[Id]) LOOKUP ORDERED FORWARD)",1,9,6,Clustered Index Seek,Clustered Index Seek,"OBJECT:([LocalDatabase].[dbo].[ExampleTable].[PK_ExampleTable]), SEEK:([LocalDatabase].[dbo].[ExampleTable].[Id]=[LocalDatabase].[dbo].[ExampleTable].[Id]) LOOKUP ORDERED FORWARD",[LocalDatabase].[dbo].[ExampleTable].[PreviousObjects],1,0.003125,0.0001581,4035,0.0034412,[LocalDatabase].[dbo].[ExampleTable].[PreviousObjects],NULL,ExampleTable_ROW,0,2

---

Rows,Executes,StmtText,StmtId,NodeId,Parent,PhysicalOp,LogicalOp,Argument,DefinedValues,EstimateRows,EstimateIO,EstimateCPU,AvgRowSize,TotalSubtreeCost,OutputList,Warnings,Type,Parallel,EstimateExecutions
14000,1,"SELECT *
FROM OPENJSON(@json) 
WITH ( 
    [Id] NVARCHAR(100),
    [ElementTimestamp] DATETIME2,
    [Hash] NVARCHAR(500)
)",2,1,0,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,50,NULL,NULL,NULL,5.0157E-05,NULL,NULL,SELECT,0,NULL
14000,1,"  |--Table-valued function",2,2,1,Table-valued function,Table-valued function,NULL,NULL,50,0,5.0157E-05,621,5.0157E-05,"OPENJSON_EXPLICIT.[Id], OPENJSON_EXPLICIT.[ElementTimestamp], OPENJSON_EXPLICIT.[Hash]",NULL,PLAN_ROW,0,1
```

*Note: In my local setup, I actually had 14k rows, not 10k as described.*

*Both sets of Statistics/IO profiles were recorded in a local docker setup, however similar results were observed in an Azure SQL environment*

What's going on?

Comment: Is the Timestamp column indexed?  Is the Id column the primary key?

Comment: Maybe your environment is limited by network bandwidth (not by CPU or disk reading speed). In this case, it would be relevant that the size of the second result set is less that the size of the entire JSON (because it does not contain the tags for each row).

Comment: One requires sorting. You can look at the costs of the query operators using the lightweight profiling feature to see where things are expensive

Comment: @ConorCunninghamMSFT: both queries require sorting.

Comment: Apologies - I misread the second example on my phone app.  There is nothing obvious from what you have posted that would explain the difference.  There are different query plans for each example, but they do approximately the same thing algorithmically.  I suggest you use "set statistics profile on" for your example (as you have data and your post does not) to see if there are big differences that show there in the row counts per operator

Comment: How many rows are in the table. I made a same example successfully and tried these two queries. The query performance is similar, only the difference is CPU cost.

Comment: Added Statistics and IO profiles for each query to the Question. Note that for the second query I am getting 0 lob logical read and 0 log read-ahead reads. This in itself might be a signficant clue.

While my example uses a relatively simple JSON object model, in practice, I have around 10 properties per element, which would obviously increase the length of my column.

Perhaps part of the reduced speed with the raw value is related to the additional cache paging?

I suspect @RazvanSocol could also on to something with regards to the result set size being smaller due to the omitted tags?

Comment: You've got a difference between reading a large blob (something that requires special attention to do efficiently) and reading a lot of smaller rows (which does not). The inefficiency should be on the client side, not the server side. First off, try adding `Packet Size=32767` to your connection string to side-step the sensitivity TDS has to data straddling packet boundaries. For the rest, you'd have to dig deeper in how the values are processed. Naive client code that fetches the whole thing as a huge string will be slow. `DBCC DROPCLEANBUFFERS` will allow you to time on a cold cache.

Comment: Probably 1 of three things the first two are parameter sniffing or buffer sizes for large rows which are documented elsewhere.  I've also seen some interesting results when the local system is expecting a different character set and big buffers have to convert from one character set to another for transit.